# Mongoose 'static' methods vs. 'instance' methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I believe this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425303/what-is-the-difference-between-methods-and-statics-in-mongoose) but the terminology is different. From the Mongoose 4 [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods):

> We may also define our own custom document instance methods too.

```
// define a schema
var animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });

// assign a function to the "methods" object of our animalSchema
animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function (cb) {
  return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
}
```

> Now all of our animal instances have a findSimilarTypes method available to it.

And then:

> Adding static methods to a Model is simple as well. Continuing with our animalSchema:

```
// assign a function to the "statics" object of our animalSchema
animalSchema.statics.findByName = function (name, cb) {
  return this.find({ name: new RegExp(name, 'i') }, cb);
}

var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);
Animal.findByName('fido', function (err, animals) {
  console.log(animals);
});
```

It seems with static methods each of the animal instances would have the `findByName` method available to it as well.  What are the `statics` and `methods` objects in a Schema? What is the difference and why would I use one over the other?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

`statics` are the methods defined on the Model. `methods` are defined on the document (instance).

You might use a **static** method like `Animal.findByName`:

```
const fido = await Animal.findByName('fido');
// fido => { name: 'fido', type: 'dog' }
```

And you might use an instance **method** like `fido.findSimilarTypes`:

```
const dogs = await fido.findSimilarTypes();
// dogs => [ {name:'fido',type:'dog} , {name:'sheeba',type:'dog'} ]
```

But you wouldn't do `Animals.findSimilarTypes()` because Animals is a model, it has no "type". `findSimilarTypes` needs a `this.type` which wouldn't exist in Animals model, only a document instance would contain that property, as defined in the model.

Similarly you wouldn't¹ do `fido.findByName` because `findByName` would need to search through all documents and `fido` is just ***a*** document.

¹Well, technically you *can*, because instance does have access to the collection ([`this.constructor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684673/is-it-possible-to-get-the-model-from-the-document-in-mongoose) or `this.model('Animal')`) but it wouldn't make sense (at least in this case) to have an instance method that doesn't use any properties from the instance. (thanks to [@AaronDufour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664499/mongoose-static-methods-vs-instance-methods/29664606#comment47469572_29664606) for pointing this out)

Comment: @laggingreflex Your second comment is not true.  You _could_ have `fido.findByName`, since `fido` does have access to the entire collection (via `this.model('Animal')`).  However, it doesn't make much sense to have an instance method that doesn't use any properties from the instance.

Comment: @lagginreflex did you write the docs on mongoosejs.com that uses the actual word `static` for free stack points here? lol 
It actually shows the example the way @Startec did it, with `Animal.statics.methodName` but then you come along, as one of the few resources i found thus far on this, and say, dont use the word `statics` basically, e.g. `Animals.methodName`, but on the docs it shows to.  Thanks for this, and i suspected this.

Answer (score 4):

Database logic should be encapsulated within the data model. Mongoose provides 2 ways of doing this, methods and statics. Methods adds an instance method to documents whereas Statics adds static “class” methods to the Models itself.The static keyword defines a static method for a model. Static methods aren't called on instances of the model. Instead, they're called on the model itself. These are often utility functions, such as functions to create or clone objects. like example below:

```
const bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type : String,
    required : [true, 'Book name required']
  },
  publisher : {
    type : String,
    required : [true, 'Publisher name required']
  },
  thumbnail : {
    type : String
  }
  type : {
    type : String
  },
  hasAward : {
    type : Boolean
  }
});

//method
bookSchema.methods.findByType = function (callback) {
  return this.model('Book').find({ type: this.type }, callback);
};

// statics
bookSchema.statics.findBooksWithAward = function (callback) {
  Book.find({ hasAward: true }, callback);
};

const Book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);
export default Book;
```

for more info: https://osmangoni.info/posts/separating-methods-schema-statics-mongoose/

Answer (score 3):

**As everybody said, use methods when we want to operate on a single document, and we use statics when we want to operate on entire collection.** But why?

Let's say, we have a schema:

```
var AnimalSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String
});
```

now as mentioned in the docs, **if** you need to check the similar types of a particular **document** in the db
you can do:

```
AnimalSchema.methods.findSimilarType = function findSimilarType (cb) {
    return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
};
```

Now, **this** here refers to the document itself. So, what that means is, this document
doesn't knows which model it belongs to, because **methods** has nothing to do with the model defaultly, It's only for that particular document obj.
But we **can** make it work with the model, using this.model('anyModelName').

Now why did we used methods in the case of finding similar types of animals?

For finding similar types of animals we *must* have **an animal obj** for which we'll find similar types of.
That animal obj we have let's say:

```
const Lion = await new Animal({name: Lion, type: "dangerous"});
```

Next, when we find similar types we **need** the Lion obj first, we **must** have it.
So simply, whenever we need the help of a particular obj/document for doing something, We'll use methods.

Now here **by chance** we also need whole model to search slimier types,
**although** it is not available directly in methods (remember **this.modelName** will return undefined). we can get it by setting this.model() to our preferred model, in this case Animal.
That's all for methods.

Now, **statics** has the whole model at its disposal.
1)Let's say you want to calculate the total **price** (assume the model has a price field) of all Animals you'll use statics [for that you don't need any particular Animal obj, so we won't use method]
2)You want to find the animals which have yellow skin (assume the model has a skin field), you'll use statics. [ for that we don't need any particular Animal obj, so we won't use method]

eg:

```
 AnimalSchema.statics.findYellowSkin = function findSimilarType (cb) {
        return this.find({ skin: "yellow" }, cb);
    };
```

Remember, In methods **this** refers to the model so, **this.modelName** will return **Animal** (in our case).

but just like methods, here also we **can** (but we don't need to) set the model using.

```
AnimalSchema.methods.findSimilarType = function findSimilarType (cb) {
    return this.model('Animal').find({ skin: "yellow" }, cb);   //just like in methods
};
```

so as you can see both of statics and methods are very similar.

> Whenever you have a document and you need something to do with that,
> use methods. Whenever you need to do something with the whole
> model/collection, use statics.

Answer (score 2):

Well to me it doesn't mean add anythings by adding **Mongoose** in front of 'static' or even in front 'instance' keyword.

What I believe meaning and purpose of static is same everywhere,  even it's also true for an alien language or some sort of driver which represents Model for building the block like another object-oriented programming. The same also goes for instance.

**From Wikipedia:**
**A method** in object-oriented programming (OOP) is a procedure associated with a message and an object. An object consists of data and behavior. The data and behavior comprise an interface, which specifies how the object may be utilized by any of various consumers[1] of the object.

Data is represented as properties of the object and behaviors are represented as methods of the object. For example, a Window object could have methods such as open and close, while its state (whether it is opened or closed at any given point in time) would be a property.

**Static methods** are meant to be relevant to all the instances of a class rather than to any specific instance. They are similar to static variables in that sense. An example would be a static method to sum the values of all the variables of every instance of a class. For example, if there were a Product class it might have a static method to compute the average price of all products.

Math.max(double a, double b)

This static method has no owning object and does not run on an instance. It receives all information from its arguments.[7]

A static method can be invoked even if no instances of the class exist yet. Static methods are called "static" because they are resolved at compile time based on the class they are called on and not dynamically as in the case with instance methods, which are resolved polymorphically based on the runtime type of the object.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 1):

`Static methods` apply to the entire model on which they are defined whereas `instance methods` apply only to a specific document within the collection.

`this` in the context of a static method returns the entire model whereas `this` in the context of an instance method returns the document.

Lets say for example:

```js
const pokemon = new mongoose.Schema({})
pokemon.statics.getAllWithType = function(type){
      // Query the entire model and look for pokemon
      // with the same type
      // this.find({type : type})
}

pokemon.methods.sayName = function(){
      // Say the name of a specific pokemon
      // console.log(this.name)
}


const pokemonModel = mongoose.model('schema', pokemon)
const squirtle = new pokemonModel({name : "squirtle"})

// Get all water type pokemon from the model [static method]
pokemonModel.getAllWithType("water")

// Make squirtle say its name [instance method] 
squirtle.sayName()
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `.statics` for `static` methods.
- Use `.methods` for `instance` methods.

```
//instance method
bookSchema.methods.findByType = function (callback) {
  return this.model('Book').find({ type: this.type }, callback);
};

// static method
bookSchema.statics.findBooksWithAward = function (callback) {
  Book.find({ hasAward: true }, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`statics` are pretty much the same as `methods` but allow for defining functions that exist directly on your Model.

`statics` belongs to the **Model** and `methods` belongs to an **Instance**