# Calling custom method from mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I made custom methods with two ways, But not working.

models

```
...
// I read it from other stack overflow QA
categorySchema.methods.postChange = function(){
console.log('postChange');
};

// Mongoose reference doc
categorySchema.methods('postChange', function(){
console.log('postChange');
});

var Category = mongoose.model('category',categorySchema);

module.exports = Category;
```

routes

```
...
router.post('/update_cat', upload.single('image_file'), function(req, res){
Category.findOneAndUpdate({name: req.body.name}, {href: req.body.href}, function(err, doc){
    doc.href = req.body.href;
    Category.postChange();
    (err)?res.json(err):res.redirect('./reg_line');
    });
});
```

and The error is 'Category.postChange is not a function'.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable to put your function in the models but you should define them in the routes itself. Models are for your mongoose schema. Just in case, you are getting this error because you are not **exporting** the function.

```
exports.categorySchema.methods.postChange = function(){
     console.log('postChange');
};
```

or

```
exports.categorySchema.methods('postChange', function(){
     console.log('postChange');
});
```

Comment: var Category = mongoose.model('category',categorySchema);

Comment: You have to explicitly export them if you want to use in the routes, as when you `exports` your schema, it doesn't mean you are exporting other function of the file as well. If you are accustomed with `node.js`, you must have observed that either you put all your functions inside a class object and export them or you explicitly export all the functions.

Comment: I can't entirely agree with what you've said, it's better to place all the logic related to the documents in the schema methods. it abstracts too much unnecessary complexity from being handled in the routes

Answer (score 0):

You can set the function as *static* with this code :

```
// Mongoose reference doc
categorySchema.statics.postChange = function(){
    console.log('postChange');
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('category',categorySchema);
```

**Documentation :** http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics

Answer (score 0):

As meantioned in the answer above me by @F.kauder - in the demo route (/update_cat) you attached - you are tring to use a static function - hence you are calling

```
Category.postChange();
```

However your definition on the schema is for a method on an instance.

You can read more about the difference here: [Mongoose 'static' methods vs. 'instance' methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664499/mongoose-static-methods-vs-instance-methods)