# Could you please explain in simple words what Instance methods are while using mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, methods, instance

Am I wrong if I say that this code is not clear?

I understand more or less what this should do but... 
I guess that we are looking at objects that have the same type in a collection?

The things are the way they wrote this code sounds not really clear for me. Can you please provide a better example or correct this one?

Many thanks

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

```
 // define a schema
 var animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });

 // assign a function to the "methods" object of our animalSchema
 animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function(cb) {
   return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
 };
```

Now all of our animal instances have a `findSimilarTypes` method available to them.

```
 var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);
 var dog = new Animal({ type: 'dog' });

 dog.findSimilarTypes(function(err, dogs) {
   console.log(dogs); // woof
 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose 'static' methods vs. 'instance' methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664499/mongoose-static-methods-vs-instance-methods)

Answer (score 1):

A Mongoose modelschema declaration is more or less like a Class declaration, so it's more or less like this:

```
    class Person {
        constructor (name, yearOfBirth, job) {
            this.name = name;
            this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
            this.job = job;
        }

        calculateAge() {
            var age = new Date().getFullYear - this.yearOfBirth;
            console.log(age);
        }
    }

    const john6 = new Person6('John', 1990, 'teacher');

john6.calculateAge() // Returns age
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the docs have a very unintuitive way of explaining things. Let's go over the basics of creating a model, shall we?
You define a schema -

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  // any random Schema
  var animal_SCHEMA = new Schema({
    name:  String,
    type: String
  });
```

> You can define your own methods that your ***model instances*** can use.

Taking the example from the docs, the way to create an instance method is -

```js
animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function() {
    return mongoose.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }); //I omitted the callback for simplicity
  };
```

Then, you make a model and may export it. Here I'm just creating the model.

```js
var animal_MODEL = mongoose.model('Animals', animal_SCHEMA);
```

So now you created a model and an instance instance for the *model instances*, but where's the instance that will use it? Let's create one. This is how you normally create an **instance** of your model. Nothing new about it.

```js
var newAnimal = new animal_MODEL({name:"Scobby", type:"Detective"}); // this can use findSimilarTypes
```

You're probably comfortable to create such new instances and save them, usually like -

```js
const savedData = await newAnimal.save();
```

Ever wondered about the `save()` method? Well, that's an example of an instance method! Mongoose supplies `save()` by default along with a bunch of other methods, see the [API docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html).

> They are called so because they only come with an *instance* of an object.

Every instance of a model you create has some built-in *instance methods*. The one you defined earlier, that's an *instance method* that is custom and made by you.
Now, `newAnimal` can use this method.

> In fact, all new instances you spawn for this model will have access to the `findSimilarTypes` method.

```js
var badAnimal = new animal_MODEL({name:"Scrappy", type:"Trouble Maker"});
var trouble_makers = badAnimal.findSimilarTypes();
console.log(trouble_makers);
```